# JMeter - Create Custom Property File

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a script with User Defined Variables[image]

These are to be defined as a property in a custom property file (other than jmeter or user properties)

Also, in the groovy script (JSR223 Sampler) a file location needs to be parameterized into the same custom property file.

[image]

Please let me know if there is a way out. Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the following lines to i.e. `custom.properties` file:

```
Host=10.184.192.248
User=root
Pass=install
FileLocation=C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/Service_Names.csv
```

Then you can "tell" JMeter to read this property file via [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -q /path/to/custom.properties -t /path/to/testplan.jmx .....
```

And finally you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the properties values in the User Defined Variables:

```
${__P(host,)}
```

[image]

In the JSR223 Sampler you can use [`props` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to retrieve `FileLocation` property value like:

```
f = new File(props.get('FileLocation'))
```